# Textfields in a Grid not responsive when it is under a tab

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a component under a tab and because of that it makes the `Textfield` not responsive when it is on a small screen. This is what the `Textfield` looks like in small screen sizes when I tried checking what it looks like in iphone 5/SE screen size.

[image]

How can I make this responsive? I have recreated this in [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-spence-02w2b?file=/src/App.js&fbclid=IwAR3ZFAu6yl3C5KDpe_kGQitKF9T4UmD01FFaGrPpaRgZNWK26tpiBWOF2DM)

Comment: I encountered the same problem. You have 2 solutions here. Use row instead of column for Grid container and send xs={12}. Alternatively (recommended), use https://next.material-ui.com (v5) and use the Stack component instead of Grid. You should very well be using v5 instead of v4 as it's pretty stable right now and have lot of new goodies.

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial OP is using v4, but yes, `Stack` is the ultimate solution in v5 for this layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Grid` item, add `xs={12}` to tell the grid item expand to `100%` width of its parent, alongside with setting the `fullWidth` prop of the `TextField`. See more examples about how you can divide the grid item [here](https://mui.com/components/grid/#basic-grid).

```
<Grid item xs={12}>
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: Thank you for this. Also, if I'll upgrade to v5, should I re-code most of what I've already done?

Comment: @Jenn If you update to v5, you can replace the `Grid` with a [`Stack`](https://mui.com/components/stack/#main-content) instead, it will make the layout simpler. But v5 has a lot of changes, so be sure to skim the [announcement post](https://mui.com/blog/mui-core-v5/) first to see if you're ready to upgrade then.